# Windows PowerShell Select removing columns

Tags: powershell, wmi, windows

I am a linux guy so I'm used to "grep".  With grep it keeps the columns, however in powershell it changes the output.  For example:

```
Get-WmiObject -List | Select-String -Pattern "Win32_LogicalDisk$"

\\COMP\ROOT\cimv2:Win32_LogicalDisk
```

Where as "Get-WmiObject -List" puts out the columns such as:

```
  CIM_Tachometer                      {SetPowerState, R... {Accuracy, Availability, Caption, ConfigManagerErrorCode...
```

I would like my "Select" to yield the entire column as opposed to just the object or whatever it's returning.  I would like to emulate a grep of the actual output of Get-WmiObject -List

Also as a bouns side question:
Besides MSDN what is a good site that lists all the WMI objects and what they return?  These seem like a super powerful way to get information about any aspect of a windows system.  AmIRight?

Comment: Yes you are right that WMI is a powerful way to get information about a Windows system, and it not only gives information, but also has methods that actually take actions too!

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to use `Select-String`. Powershell offers [`Where-Object`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177028.aspx) cmdlet for this sort of filtering:

```
Get-WmiObject -List | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "Win32_LogicalDisk" }
```

You may also use [`Select-Object`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176955.aspx)  to expand the property "Properties" on the object returned from `Where-Object`:

```
Get-WmiObject -List | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "Win32_LogicalDisk" } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Properties
```

If you want to explore WMI, there are many tools available.  One Powershell version, [WMI Explorer](http://tfl09.blogspot.com/2013/03/wmi-explorerwheres-it-gonea-temporary.html) may be of particular interest to you.